# Taking the odd photo that is confidential and shouldn't be synced or posted anywhere

Tags: security, camera, privacy, google-photos

I use Google Photos to backup all photos. For my camera app I use OpenCamera. On the occasion I take a picture of something confidential (for work or personal use). What is the easiest/best way to to take a picture and have it only stored locally on the phone (even better if password protected)?

I tried putting the phone in airplane mode but this doesn't work so well as I need to use the internet before I can delete the picture.

I tried turning off google photos temporarily but this is tedious and I think there's other apps that automatically get the picture, for example Facebook was asking me if I wanted to post the new picture and gave a preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Signal Messenger](https://signal.org/en/). It has the option to send notes to self.

Answer (score 0):

Use any file browser and rename you image extension to say .xyz. As its not a image file anymore no app will take it as image and will not sync it. When you want to view that image just open it as image. Best file browser to do this is ES File Explorer and is available on Play Store.

Comment: That would still require him to turn off the internet before naming the picture.